# Custom character mapping for System.String in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm working on a C# project which requires a custom string case mapping.

After doing some research I have found that in order to do this I need to create a custom culture using `CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CreateFromLdml` which loads an [LDML](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/) XML file which is based on en_US but has my custom case mapping rules applied. However, after reading all of the applicable documentation I can't seem to understand how one would structure this XML file.

An example of some the custom case maps I need to make are:

```
Upper | Lower
----- | ------
(     | )
{     | }
[     | ]
<     | >
\     | /
```

Comment: Asking the obvious question: what happens if you *just* write a custom case-conversion method (`static string MyCustomToUpper(string)`, etc) - and explicitly call that method instead if `value.ToUpper(myCustomCulture)` ?

Comment: It is unfortunately not an option as I need to be able to do things like have case insensitive comparisons like with `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`.

Comment: What are you using the custom case mapping for? Is it for changing case, comparison operations or both?